# Is it possible to create an irregular raster in R with terra package?

Tags: raster, r, sf, terra

I have a dataset which represents a global grid with latitude and longitude and the length of each pixel along the x and y axis. These are simply lat/long CRS.

Like this

```
head(latlong)
   x      y     x.leng  y.leng   value 
80.221 50.854  72334 16027.8       0.1
80.000 50.214  32132  2404.4       0.2
79.779 50.214  72334 16027.8       0.6
79.664 50.854  77632 23841.8       0.5
79.572 51.548  80556 29873.3       0.3
79.491 52.270  82574 34953.4       0.2
```

[image: this is how the grid looks like]
Where x and y are the center of the cell and leng is the total length of the cell in the two directions.
Because I have to do area-based calculations like extracting the values of cells in a raster that overlap with polygons, I cannot convert to a regular-sized raster and I don't want to interpolate values. So the functions `rasterize` and `rasterXYZ` don't work for me.

[image: this is the result of rasterize]

I know `rast` objects can have irregular-sized cells when they are projected but I am not sure how to set this up from the above data frame.

Should I consider creating a multi-polygon simple feature? What are my options?